# Code generation for struct property of user control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, struct, windows-forms-designer

I create a user control like below:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public State MyState
    {
        get { return new State(this); }
    }

    internal int[] _internalStates;

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public struct State
    {
        private TestControl _myControl;
        public State(TestControl _) { _myControl = _; }
        public int Data
        {
            get { return _myControl._internalStates[0]; }
            set { _myControl._internalStates[0] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can drag the control from toolbox and modify the `Data` value in the designer.

[image: property]

The problem is the designer will generate this code in `InitializeComponent` method:

```
this.testControl1.MyState.Data = 0;
```

But this line will throw an error:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'TestControl.MyState' because it is not a variable

I understand why the statement is error, the question is **how can I control the code generation** to correct the error, for example to generate code like this?

```
var myState = this.testControl1.MyState;
myState.Data = 0;
```

---

More information

- `State` struct is just a bridge to modify the internal property in `TestControl`
- So I want to keep `State` as a struct to avoid GC overhead.
- The reason for not define property in `TestControl` class is there are multiple states in the class, and a state will contain multiple properties, so I need to wrap the modification methods rather than define a lot of properties in the `TestControl` class.

Comment: You can't. The problem is not with the designer. `State` is a struct. A struct is a value type. Your property `MyState` has only a getter, it is read-only. Hence the value of the property MyState (the value being the struct) cannot be modified. Your last code example will not modify the value of testControl1.MyState.Data, because a struct is not a reference type. (the value of the `myState` variable will only be a copy of the `this.testControl1.MyState` property value, and thus be completely independent and distinct from it)

Comment: `var myState = this.testControl1.MyState; myState.Data = 0;` will compile, but still is wrong, it will not change `MyState` property. At least for this statement the problem is obvious, for example `var i = 0; var j = i; j = 1;` will it change `i`? While I suggest using classes for such properties, but if you want to generate the code for struct property correctly, you need an `InstanceDescription` as I described in the answer.

Comment: @elgonzo thanks for your explanation, but I understand the error, the code is auto generated, so I just want to find a way let the designer generate correct code for the property assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why a compile time error for `Control.StructProperty.Member = Value;`?**

Consider the following statement

```
this.Control.StructProperty.Value = 0;
```

`StructProperty` is a property, so first its getter will execute and since it's a structure and is a value type, it will return a copy of the struct and setting a property for that copy is not useful/working. The knows about the situation well and instead of compiling a confusing non-working code, it generates [Compiler Error CS1612](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1612):

> Cannot modify the return value of 'expression' because it is not a
> variable

**How can I generate a working code for a Struct property?**

You probably have noticed that you cannot assign `this.Size.Width = 100` with the same reason. And the way that form generates the code for `Size` property is:

```
this.Size = new Size(100,100);
```

You also can generate code for the property the same way, by implementing a type descriptor by deriving from `TypeConverter` returning an [`InstanceDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.instancedescriptor?view=netframework-4.7.2&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) in its `ConvertTo` method to generate the code for your structure property using a parametric constructor which you should have for the struct.

In general, I suggest using classes rather that structures for such property.

Comment: Yes the statement "`this.Size.Width = 100`" is invalid, so usually the `Width` property won't be shown in the properties panel, there is only `Size` property. And as you see my code, the constructor for `State` need an instance of `TestControl`, I cannot image how to get that instance.

Comment: For an example of such type descriptor that I described in the answer take a look at Take a look at [`InstanceDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.instancedescriptor?view=netframework-4.7.2), it has a god example. All types like `Point` or `Size` have such type descriptor.

Comment: Story of width property is different. `Size` property will show and you can edit it. Anyway, I believe the answer is describing the situation well and you have all the information you need. Read the first part of the answer carefully to understand why `this.Control.StructProperty.Value = 0;` is invalid and understand the reason of compiler error. Then read the second part of the answer to learn about the solution.

Comment: I understand the first part, that's why I need control the generation, and I've read the code for [SizeConverter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/SizeConverter.cs,86ceb450bb606020), the `Size` structure contains width and height members, so it's easy to construct a `InstanceDescriptor`, but my `State` structure has no fields to use.

Comment: You need to redesign the structure, IMO a a struct pointing to an array outside of the struct and also having a reference of the control is not a good struct. However the quickest fix would be using a class.